# OS x command backtick historic order

Tags: macos, mac

In Mac OS x, I want to switch between different windows of the same app. If I have three or more windows, command + backtick cycles all the windows instead of the two most recently used ones like command-tab to cycle between program does.

I want the historic order. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: No, as far as I'm concerned, the whole idea is "cycling" through windows, no Most-Recently-Used switching like with `⌘⇥`. I don't think there's a solution to this yet.

Comment: I don't find cycling as useful. No third party app to override the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) and configure the trigger `Cycle Windows...` `Frontmost application` to <kbd>⌘ `</kbd> and <kbd>⇧⌘ `</kbd>. That will allow you to switch back and forth between the most recently used windows of an app, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've not tried it yet. These days I've just resort to apps with tabs and just Cmd-3 and Cmd-4 to switch between the 3rd and the 4th tabs, for example. This kind of walks around the issue.